# Keep the first row id using qualify in Teradata

Tags: sql-order-by, teradata, partitioning, row-number

I have the following example data for one id. I am trying to sum the amount for distinct Serial but keep the first occurrence of Id2 and Date.

Have

```
Id    Id2     Serial   Date         Amount
101   201     10001    4/15/2020      150
101   301     10002    4/17/2020       20
101   401     10001    4/17/2020      100
101   501     10002    4/19/2020       50
```

Want

```
 Id     Id2     Serial     Date       Amount
 101   201       10001    4/15/2020      250
 101   301       10002    4/17/2020       70
```

I tried the following

```
    Select distinct
     Id,Serial,Id2,Date,sum(Amount) as Amount 
     from Have group by 1,2,3
    Qualify row_number() over (partition by Id, Serial order by Serial)=1
```

This gives me

```
101   401     10001    4/17/2020      100
101   501     10002    4/19/2020       50
```

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

The other way around. Put the one SUM in all the rows and then pick one.

```
Select Id, Id2, Serial, Date, sum(Amount) over (Partition by Id, Serial)
from Have
qualify row_number() over (Partition by ID, Serial order by Serial)=1
```